# Distinct elements count of huge multiset

Tags: algorithms, sets, bloom-filters

I know that *HyperLogLog* can approximate the distinct elements count of a huge multiset but I was wondering if it was possible, using a method I saw mentioned on an IRC channel, to get an exact answer while still using significantly less space than a traditional approach.

Would the following work to compute the exact (not approximate) distinct elements count of a huge multiset?

The idea is to use a *Bloom filter* twice, first processing the data one way, and then in reverse and additionally using a map (whose size is much smaller than the huge multiset -- this property is provided by the Bloom filter).

```
1st pass
create an empty bloom filter
create an empty map
for each element from the multiset
    if already in the bloom add to the map with key element / value 0
    else add to the bloom
```

Second pass is nearly identical but elements from the huge multiset are processed in reverse (multiset doesn't need to be an ordered set: it simply needs to have its elements iterated from the end to its beginning).

```
2nd pass
    empty the bloom filter (but not the set)
    for each element from the multiset (but processed this time in reverse order)
        if already in the bloom add to the map with key element / value 0
        else add to the bloom
```

At this point the map contains a list of potentially, but not necessarily, clashing entries in the multiset. So the entries are all set to zero.

```
3rd pass
   cnt = 0
   for each element in the multiset
       if present in the map, increment value in that map for that key
       else increment cnt
```

Exact cardinality is now equal to `"cnt + nb entries in the map whose value is 1 or greater"`.

This requires three passes but uses space identical to a *Bloom filter* plus a map to count the x% of entries the *Bloom filter* couldn't answer if they were present or not.

I hacked a quick proof of concept and did some generative testing and it seemed to give the correct answer but I'm really not sure.

Is it possible to compute the exact distinct element count of a huge multiset this way?

Comment: Using *cardinality* is misleading. You're after the number of *distinct* elements in the multiset.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *map*? Also, what is the traditional approach, how much space does it use, and how much space does your proposed method use?

Comment: How does your method compare to using a dynamically resizing hash table? For each element, we check whether it is already found in the hash table, and if not, put it there, and increment a counter.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: but I wrote the space usage in the question: it's the same space usage as a Bloom filter uses for space-efficiency usage plus an associative array used to count the elements for which the Bloom Filter couldn't answer _"definitely not in set"_. The advantage being the space efficiency of the Bloom Filter and a hash table about 1% of the size of the size if counting using only a hash table?

Comment: You're asking whether your algorithm is correct. Have you tried *proving* that it is correct? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: I'm no computer scientist. I'm a software developer. I did write a proof of concept and used generative testing (using QuickCheck) to try on many inputs. I couldn't prove that it is incorrect. But this doesn't mean it is correct.

Comment: I was referring to *mathematical proof*, the kind that you learn when completing a BA/BSc in computer science.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: but isn't that what this site is also for? The FAQ says: _"This site covers theoretical and applied computer science at any level, including but not limited to: algorithms, models of computation"_.  Isn't it allowed here to ask an algorithmic question if you don't have a CS degree? I thought that maybe somehow with a CS degree could either validate or invalidate this algorithm?

Comment: From Wikipedia: _"HyperLogLog is an algorithm for the count-distinct problem, approximating the number of distinct elements in a multiset.[1] Calculating the exact cardinality of a multiset requires an amount of memory proportional to the cardinality"_. Are they using the term cardinality in a misleading way too?

Comment: I edited the question to replace "cardinality of the multiset" with "distinct elements" but the method, if it works, can compute both I think.

Comment: There might be easier methods to compute the cardinality of the multiset...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: yes of course!

Comment: It took me some time to see the merit of pass 2: can you please add your take to the question?

Comment: `using a map (whose size is much smaller than the huge multiset -- this property is provided by the Bloom filter)` How is this provided? Third pass simplified or not, in the worst case, your map/set will need to contain $\frac n 2 $ items for a multiset of $n$ items.  (Imagine being promised $2n$ values, $n$ *or* $n+1$ distinct, $n$ or $n-1$ appearing twice.)  
And (for any false-positive ratio targeted) the Bloom filter will need space proportional to $n_{distinct}$  (not known in advance; potentially *much* smaller than $n$, let alone the cumulative size of all items).

Comment: @greybeard: worst case for the map/set is even _n/2_ after first pass and then _n_ after second pass no? If there are only two elements and they collide in the Bloom filter, than after pass 1 map/set shall have 1st element  and after pass 2 it'll have both. But Bloom filter is using parameters to target a 99% of "definitely not in set answers" (a reasonable target for a Bloom filter), then doing the two passes shouldn't create anything near that worst case? Don't you think that practically this would use very little additional space?

Comment: `Don't you think that practically this would use very little additional space?` Entirely. I'd just prefer a comment on worst case requirements to go with a presentation of the approach (then again, with $u$ the number of distinct values, the $+O(u)$ space requirement may be too obvious to mention). (The $\frac n 2$ is from an ill-conceived reasoning about "the number of values occurring twice" case.)

Comment: EDIT: the idea wasn't mine but I saw it mentioned on IRC

Answer (score 3):

Let me simplify your third step: count the number of elements in your multiset which are not in the map, and add to it the number of elements in the map.

Suppose that your elements are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. For a given hash $h$, let $x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_\ell}$ be the elements hashing to $h$ (in order). If $\ell = 1$, then the elements won't be added to the map in the first or second step. Otherwise, elements $x_{i_2},\ldots,x_{i_\ell}$ will be added to the map in the first step, and elements $x_{i_{\ell-1}},\ldots,x_{i_1}$ will be added to the map in the second step.

In total, this shows that after the first two steps, the map will contain all elements whose hash appears more than once.

After the third step, *cnt* will contain the number of elements whose hash appears exactly once. All of these elements are distinct, and also distinct from the elements in the map. You then add to *cnt* the number of elements present in the map, and so obtain the number of distinct elements.